# jquery php : json_encode or echo?

Tags: jquery, json, echo, encode

is it not necessary to call the json_encode function in the php page, with an Ajax method?
for example, i found this code :

> $.post('updatecoords.php', 'data='+$.toJSON(order), function(response){
>   if(response=="success")

and at the end of the php page :

> echo "success";
>   ?>

So here is "echo", instead of json_encode ($array). It's one or another? or is there any rule?
Thanks for the answer! ;)

Comment: Could you better explain what you are trying to accomplish? And there is no `$.toJSON` method, are you using a plugin?

Comment: @NeXXeuS : it comes from there : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/simple-draggable-element-persistence-with-jquery/  i thought the toJSON strange also, but since i'm quite a beginner... you can see the code in the middle of the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is only a format for passing data around. In AJAX calls it makes more sense to encode the data as JSON and pass it to the browser because a simple `eval` of the JSON string is all that has to be done by the clientside javascript. It is not necessary to use JSON for AJAX calls though. You can return anything from full fledged HTML pages to a simple string as the response to an AJAX call. You just have to make sure that your client side code can handle the response correctly.